# Dataset Theme Issue

Tags: dataset

In watching Stephen Wolfram introduce Vers. 12.3, I installed the upgrade from 12.2 and executed the following statement as he did in his presentation:

```
  Dataset[IdentityMatrix[6], DatasetTheme -> "AlternatingColumnBackgrounds", LightGreen]
```

However, unlike him, I see the following output in which the return is merely the list of the 6 by 6 identity matrix rather than the expected visualization seen in his presentation, but with the standard lightgreen color box being converted to its defining RGB color.

Dataset[{{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}},
DatasetTheme -> "AlternatingColumnBackgrounds", RGBColor[
0.88, 1, 0.88]]

The frontend reports no errors as to the synatax.

What am I missing here to make this work as expected?  Is there a hidden option value or environmental variable that needs to be set properly before execution to succeed?

I'm running on Windows 10, 64 bit.  I note he is working on a Mac.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Use `DatasetTheme -> {"AlternatingColumnBackgrounds", LightGreen}`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the form  `{theme, parameter}` for themes that take a parameter:

```
Dataset[IdentityMatrix[6], 
   DatasetTheme -> { "AlternatingColumnBackgrounds", LightGreen}]
```

[image]

```
Dataset[IdentityMatrix[6], 
   DatasetTheme -> {"Web", { "AlternatingColumnBackgrounds", LightGreen}}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's it.  Bad eyesight and lack of focus.  Thanks for the prompt notification.

Comment: Consider marking this answer as accepted if it solves your problem :)